# Average a block in a 3D matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a 40×40×20 array. I want to average a block of 5 in the 3rd dimension such that my output matrix is 40×40×4.

I tried the following:

```
out = zeros(size(data,1), size(data,2), size(data,3)/5);
c = 1;

for i = 1:5:size(data,3)
    out(:,:,c) = nanmean(data(:,:,i:i+5-1),3);
    c = c + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can proceed as follows:

1. Reshape into a 4D array so each block's contents are aligned along the 3rd dimension and different blocks correspond to different 4th-dimension positions;
2. Average along the 3rd dimension;
3. Remove the 3rd dimension, which is now a singleton, by permuting it to the end.

Code:

```
N = 5;                                                   % block size
out = reshape(data, size(data,1), size(data,2), N, []);  % step 1
out = nanmean(out, 3);                                   % step 2
out = permute(out, [1 2 4 3]);                           % step 3
```